# How can I port forward multiple ports on a single IP address when WAN IP is not accessible outside the country

Tags: networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, iptables

Thailand (and other countries) have a government sanctioned firewall/gateway(s) which routes all your traffic through it. As a result any LAN ports forwarded to your WAN IP, are available within Thailand but not outside. As a result my WAN IP from my Modem is different when queried through western sites like whatsmyip.org or ident.me. From what I understand this is because I go through the government gateway before being allowed to access foreign content. These gateways are public and thus will not forward my ports.

I cannot use DNS addresses in combination with cloudflare or anything like that, since I need multiple ports to be available on the same address / IP.

Here's my situation:

- Running local gaming servers each with 2-3 ports usually.
- Router configured to port forward those ports to the outside.
- Cannot access anything, from outside Thailand, since any traffic goes through the gateway which blocks the ports (again I am assuming)

My question:

1. In my current setup: Using a NordVPN Meshnet Tunnel I can connect my local server to a VPS hosted in the Netherlands (EU). This means all traffic goes through the tunnel to the Netherlands VPS. In other words the LAN of my EU VPS is the LAN I have in Thailand and I can access my devices flawlessly in the command line. Sadly I seem to be stuck forwarding ports to the outside network. (see below)
2. Does anyone know alternatives? I do not mind spending small $$ (aka <15$/month) for vps'es or services or whatever, but essentially I want my EU friends to be able to join me on my local hosted servers or in other words, reach the forwarded ports on my WAN IP.

My Research:
So after trying cloudflare zero access tunnels (no-go only single port per address),
I tried going through VPNs (no-go port forwarding generally disabled due to security risks) and finally landed on NordVPN's Meshnet service.

My ubuntu VPS in the EU has after connecting the tunnel to Thailand local LAN two different interfaces:

- ens3: EU Hypervisor Ethernet
- nordlynx: NordVPN tunnel to my Thai LAN

I can access my game server IP 192.168.1.49 flawlessly, but I seem to be struggling to port forward as I need. On the VPS Provider's side the firewall has been turned off completely (just for testing).

I am trying to port forward so the following happens:

- User visits EU-VPS-IP:5032
- port gets forwarded over nordlynx interface to 192.168.1.49:80
- User gets served the content on Port 80 on 192.168.1.49

At this point if I `curl 192.168.1.49:80` in the terminal of my EU-VPS I get the desired result, but when I visit the public IP of my EU-VPS on port 5032 I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT "This site can't be reached".

Here are the IPTables rules I tried using (to no avail):

```shell
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i nordlynx -p tcp --dport 5032 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.49:80
```

and then the guide I found [here](https://www.cloudsigma.com/forwarding-ports-with-iptables-in-linux-a-how-to-guide/), told me to add POSTROUTING rules to, so:

```shell
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nordlynx -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.1.49 -j SNAT --to-source 100.99.138.177
```

In the above examples:

- 192.168.1.49 is the LAN address of my gaming server
- 100.99.138.177 is the IP Address of the EU-VPS inside the VPS Tunnel
- The public IPv4 address of my EU-VPS I will not post here to avoid any issues since my firewall is off at this time for testing.

Am I doing something wrong? I feel like I am so close to fixing this issue for once and for all if I can just make incoming request port forward to my lan devices.

### Update

The answer @gedo provided did everything it needed to, the ports are now being forwarded, SSH tunnels bypass the government gateways / firewall (at least in Thailand) & connect directly to my VPS. As a result any and all ports forwarded to that IP are accessible in the EU without a hitch.

So far I cannot confirm it works with gaming servers yet since I am still researching that part, the ports seem to be forwarded yet no servers are found where they used to be detectable with the same config and a simple router port forwarding. Once I have more info, will update further.

Comment: What do you see in packet captures? Are the packets being forwarded to the VPS's "tunnel" interface? Do they have the expected src/dst addresses? Are they visible at the home server's interface? (Keep in mind DNAT does not *cause* packets to be forwarded – it only modifies packets that are already being forwarded, but the decision whether to forward is done before DNAT.)

Comment: Can you try `-i ens3` in your PREROUTING command instead of `-i nordlynx` (since you want to DNAT packets incoming from the external interface to your tunnel, and not packets coming from your tunnel)? Also, you shouldn't need the POSTROUTING SNAT command, since for existing connections iptables will do the inverse nat on the way back anyway.

Comment: Since `-i ens3` did not help (still, keep it this way in further tests, `-i nordlynx` is wrong here), if you want to debug more, I would focus on the firewall. First, remove all iptables rules that you added (PRE/POST), and run `nc -l 5032` (this starts a command line server listening on that port). What happens now if you try to connect to the public IP port 5032? If you still get timeout, then there is still some firewall somewhere, in that case, can you post the output to `sudo iptables-save`?

Comment: @user1686
About your first question: In packet captures (I am assuming you meant `tcpdump` since that's what google told me, I get the same line many times:
`15:44:23.686375 IP {MY_THAI_WAN_IP}.56893 > {MY_VPS_WAN_IP}.5032: Flags [S], seq 313395152, win 64240, options [mss 1452,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0`

I got this through the following command: 
`sudo tcpdump -i ens3 port 5032`

As per your second question, on my LAN I would use my router to forward the ports to the outside, how would I do this on ubuntu if not for IPTables? (since this is a rented VPS through a provider)

Comment: I assume that's the "outside" of the tunnel – it doesn't say much; what packets is it carrying inside? What does `tcpdump -n -i nordlynx` show?

Comment: You could also use a VPN that does port-forwarding.

Comment: @harrymc the problem with that is that most VPNs offer either 1 port, at which point you would need a GRE tunnel to put several packets inside one, which I didn't fully understand how to implement, or they will use upnp with random ports externally connected to your static internal ports, either way it won't work well with gaming servers since you define an address, a query port and then on that address it will expect port XXXX & YYYY to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1 of your question (update - see below for a solution with iptables that should work), you can try what I proposed in my comment, changing `-i nordlynx` to `-i ens3` in your PREROUTING iptables command. Not sure if that helps though, because you write that at the moment you are getting a timeout (I would expect a connection refused if you indeed have all firewalls open).

But I am writing here mainly an answer to part 2 of your question and suggest an easy alternative. You just need to have ssh access to any virtual machine (you can get a cheap one in many locations worldwide for around $5/month at providers like DigitalOcean, Vultr, OVH, AWS, etc...), and then you need to do the following:

- Make sure the port you want to use is open in the virtual server (depending on the provider this is different, mostly just iptables, but e.g. aws has its own firewall that you configure in the aws console).
- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the virtual server and add the line `GatewayPorts clientspecified` and restart sshd (`sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` or, in newer Ubuntu versions `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`)
- From your local machine run the command:

```
ssh -fN -R 0.0.0.0:5032:localhost:80 <virtual server>
```

(Note that the `-fN` makes this to run in the background, so this command will return immediately if everything is ok, but the ssh tunnel will be running in the background, you can check with `ps axu | grep ssh`)

- Now, anybody connecting to your virtual server public IP, port 5032 should be forwarded to your localhost port 80.

**UPDATE**

I just tried this myself in a fresh digital ocean droplet (no firewall there by default, so it is pretty easy to set up), and noticed that the `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` failed because in newer ubuntu versions it is called ssh.service. After I changed it to `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service` everything worked fine and the tunnel was created correctly. Since you mentioned it didn't work for you, can you check if this restart command failed for you, and if not, could you add some more debugging information (similar tcpdump like you did in your VPS, for starters).

**UPDATE 2**

It seems you got the ssh tunnel method working for port 80 at least, so I don't see a reason why other ports wouldn't work, but for completeness here is the explanation why your iptables method was not working as expected and how to get that one to work too:

Let's say somebody from `1.2.3.4` tries to connect to your server. You want them first to go to your VPS IP `100.99.138.177`, so the packet is coming in as `1.2.3.4 -> 100.99.138.177` from `ens3` (the public interface). You want here to change the destination address to be your internal VPN address, `192.168.1.49`. But if you just do that, your home server will get the packet as `1.2.3.4 -> 192.168.1.49` and try to reply directly to `1.2.3.4`, which will not work. That's where the SNAT part comes (mistakenly I thought it was not needed in my comment). You want the source address also to be translated to *the local address from the VPS in the nordlynx interface*! Let's call this `192.168.1.1` (you can figure out the correct one by `ip addr show nordlynx` in your VPS). So after the pre/post routing you want your packet to look like this: `192.168.1.1 -> 192.168.1.49`. On the way back, the inverse translations will be done automatically based on connection tracking in the VPS. Now in summary, this is how your commands should look like to accomplish this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 5032 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.49:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nordlynx -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.1.49 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to replace `192.168.1.1` with whatever IP address your VPS side of your vpn has.

Comment: Hey, I tried running the command with `-i ens3` but sadly same results.

When it comes to the second part of your solution, I don't think it would allow me to forward 20+ ports to the same virtual server right? Because my gaming server has many different game servers running each with their own 2-3 ports.

In other words 192.168.1.49 has 20+ ports that all need to be forwarded to EU-VPS Public IPv4 address...

(also the game server is a Ubuntu VM & The EU-VPS is an ubuntu server at a hosting company)

Comment: You can actually add many `-R` options to forward as many ports as you want, like `ssh -fN -R 0.0.0.0:5032:localhost:80 -R 0.0.0.0:5033:localhost:2345 -R 0.0.0.0:5034:localhost:5678 <virtual server>`. Also, you can run several ssh tunnel commands, e.g. if you have already 20 ports forwarded, and want to add another 3 for a new game server you just started.

Comment: Quick fyi, @gepa (trying it now, but the sshd_config file is located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ) :)

Comment: I tried using your method:
`ssh -fN -R 5032:localhost:80 {USER}@{VPS-WAN-IP}`

This did not work either, I am going to assume here that @user1686 might be correct and that the issue lies within the fact that the ports on the EU-VPS are not being forwarded to the outside yet. I disabled firewall on both the Ubuntu VPS with `ufw disable` and on the provider's web ui, but nothing, which makes me believe that they might have a behind-the-scenes-firewall maybe...

Comment: thanks, I fixed the location of `sshd_config` in my answer. Since you are getting the SYN packets in your EU-VPS (the `[S]` packets in your tcpdup), there is no external firewall involved, it is all internal in iptables. Btw, try the tcpdump command also in the server where you tried my ssh suggestion. Also, the `sudo iptables-save` output could really help if you can provide it.

Comment: your solution worked!! I can now see my WebUI of my gameserver, next up is trying to forward some of the game ports and see if people in EU can connect. If that part works too, I will update the question and mark the answer :) I think I cried a little when the UI popped up, it's been about a month of trying to get it to work so far, never thought of SSH tunnels tbh :)

Comment: I tried port forwarding a whole bunch of ports and so far multiple ports are working, so the WebUI is running, the SFTP connection is a-okay, even the telnet is fine, but the gaming servers are not. I checked and through LAN they are still available on the `192.168.1.49:XXXX` address, if those ports are all forwarded in the SSH command as said before they should work too no? Is it possible this is only TCP protocol and not UDP ? My firewall is not blocking anything so that shouldn't be the issue... I am thinking this might be an issue with how the game server works...

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is indeed only TCP that is being forwarded with the `-R` option of an ssh tunnel. I don't think you can forward UDP with an ssh tunnel. In that case you would have to go back to the iptables solution, I have updated my answer with the iptables commands that should be needed in your case. You additionally have to replace `-p tcp` with `-p udp` of course, if you want to forward udp packets.